# You've entered too many arguments excel IF error

Tags: excel

I am trying to build an IF formula but I am getting an error that I have too many arguments. Any idea how to fix this?

=IF(BZ190=$C$163,$C$163, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$165,$C$163*$C$166, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$166,$C$163*$C$167, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$167,Z190=$C$163*$C$168, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$168,$C$163*$C$169, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$169,$C$163*$C$170, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$170,$C$163*$C$171, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$171,$C$163*$C$172, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$172,$C$163*$C$173, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$173,$C$163*$C$174, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$174,$C$163*$C$175, IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$175,$C$163), IF(AND((SUM(BZ190:BZ$190)-CA$168)<0,BZ190=""),$C$163*$C$165,"")))))))))))

Comment: I suspect it should be `=IF(BZ190=$C$163,$C$163,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$165,$C$163*$C$166,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$166,$C$163*$C$167,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$167,Z190=$C$163*$C$168,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$168,$C$163*$C$169,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$169,$C$163*$C$170,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$170,$C$163*$C$171,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$171,$C$163*$C$172,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$172,$C$163*$C$173,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$173,$C$163*$C$174,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$174,$C$163*$C$175,IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$175,$C$163,IF(AND((SUM(BZ190:BZ$190)-CA$168)<0,BZ190=""),$C$163*$C$165,"")))))))))))))`

Comment: Can you please tell me what you changed? Cause it is not giving me an error but not working the way it is supposed to

Comment: You had a closing bracket before the last IF function which should not have been there.

Comment: I suspect that if you presented your underlying problem, with data samples and expected results, a much simpler (and more easily maintained) solution might be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last but one if-clause looks like this:

```
IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$175,$C$163),
                             ^
                             |
                             | bracket is obsolete
```

There should not be a bracket at the end, it should just be:

```
IF(BZ190=$C$163*$C$175,$C$163,
```

But I have another point here: imagine that, within half a year or within a year, you need to modify something. How will you find out what all those things mean? Therefore I'd advise you to use names, something like:

```
$C$163 equals "interest_rate"
$C$165 equals "student_income"
...
```

Like this, your formula will become something like:

```
IF(BZ190=interest_rate,interest_rate,
  IF(BZ190=interest_rate * student_income, ...
```

This will be much clearer to read and to maintain. And, oh, before I forget: writing the formula in multiline (one if-clause per line) also increases readability and maintainability.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dominique!